# memcpy performance vs byte shift

Tags: c, memory-management, memcpy

There are 2 variables:

```
uint32_t var32 = 0xAABBCCDD;
uint8_t var8[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Which copying way of var32 to var8 would be faster?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(uint32_t); i++)
    var8[i] = (uint8_t)(var32 >> (i * 8));
```

or

```
memcpy(var8, &var32, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

I would appreciate all hints.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a 32bit architecture, the `memcpy` comes down to a single `mov` (or similar) instruction. So it *is* faster. But it's also wrong. From a C point of view, you're invoking *implementation defined* behaviour doing that. What could happen in reality is that your bytes are ordered wrongly, depending on whether you are on a *big endian* or *little endian* platform. So, just use the bit shifting solution instead of worrying about performance.

Comment: is there a way to force endian? Just curious now. Edit: well not endian- order.

Comment: *endianness* is a property of the hardware you use (e.g. your CPU). so, no. You can check for it, though.

Comment: I mean I know im little endian in my architecture. I just thought a parameter could be passed to force certain order.

Comment: You can't _force_ an order; depending on your hardware, the `memcpy` version will either work, or leave the elements reversed.

Comment: If you *know* the endianness of the machine your code is executing on, the `memcpy` will work as expected. It's still undefined behaviour from the C standard point of view. You should consider such platform-dependent optimizations **only** if you identify the code being a **real** performance bottleneck.

Comment: I'd like a citation for your claim that `memcpy()` violates strict aliasing. (Hint: it doesn't)

Comment: @EOF you're right, it works on bytes. Still the result is undefined. Thinking about how to rephrase my answer to make that clear.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło See my answer regarding htonl to force an int into big endian.

Comment: But i need little endian

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło oh, then use htole32 instead

Comment: @Vality that's a good answer, but given the fact *most* platforms nowadays are *little endian*, it doesn't optimize anything. I stand my point not to try this kind of optimization if it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Well, the byte order isn't *undefined*, it's *implementation-defined*, so the result is not undefined either.

Comment: @EOF yes, that's the correct term, I'll update my answer, thanks.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I generally agree that the optimisation isnt needed in most cases, however the op did ask for the fastest possible implementation. The code I mentioned is the only way I know of to always generate the fastest implementation on any machine. The other thing is that htole32 often optimises to a special byte swapping opcode which is still likely faster than byte swapping by hand, but in the end it is largely immaterial and a good compiler will optimise both to the best solution. In the end if this is a real issue I would have to profile both.

Comment: Hmm, if you always treat the byte-array as a uint32_t (type cast) then there shouldn't be a problem, or is my mind on vacation too? (No network transport etc involved, so single machine)

Comment: @Jite `memcpy` operates on bytes. Of course, the result using your byte array cast to `uint32_t` will be correct in all cases. It's about accessing the single bytes in the `uint8_t` array. Enjoy your vacation, I'm on vacation, too ;)

Comment: Yeah exactly, so in reality it only matters if you plan to access the 8bit array members individually, in which case you just have to know in which order to **read** from the array. Thanks, you too. (EDIT: About memcpy; Well the basic version does yes, however the compiler will optimize it *if* *possible* to more efficient copy instructions (on ARM for instance), just watch out for alignment problems).

Answer (score 2):

The memcpy in C is generally guaranteed in modern compilers to optimise to being the fastest way of copying available. However this does assume that it is properly inlined in your implementation.

I also do not believe this causes strict aliasing violations as the two pointers never alias the same memory.

However the order of which the bytes of the int is copied into which byte of the array is implementation defined. If you wished to ensure this would instead always be in the big endian order you could first run `htonl` on the int which would make it big endian, then the results of the copy would be well defined. This would also optimise to nothing in the case it wasnt needed, making it always the fastest implementation on any system.

If on the other hand you want little endian byte ordering use the `htole32` to ensure the int becomes little endian on any hardware. However beware that `htole32` is an extension in BSD, Linux and various other OSes and isnt guaranteed to be available on all implementations (read, non standard).

Comment: +1 for a way to optimize this in a "safe" way. But still note `htole32` isn't covered by the C standard.

Comment: @FelixPalmen True on the second part, I will add a warning to the answer. And thanks.

Comment: Strict-aliasing doesn't apply with `memcpy`/`memmove` because the copy bytes (aka through `char*`). For `memcpy`, though, `dst` and `src` shall not overlap.

Answer (score -2):

I think memcpy will faster, because it dose not compute only use move. byte shift have tow step compute.

Comment: This isn't helpful. See my answer.